# Remove parent level array from set of arrays and merge nodes

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am generating menu from the database, it is working perfectly but only problem is, my `parent node` is `ROOT` which I have to remove from the array.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [label] => ROOT [url] => Array ( [0] => category/view [id] => 1 )
    [items] => Array ( 
         [0] => Array ( [label] => DESIGNERS [url] => Array ( [0] => category/view [id] => 2 ) ) 
         [1] => Array ( [label] => WOMEN [url] => Array ( [0] => category/view [id] => 3 ) [items] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [label] => CURRENT SALES [url] => Array ( [0] => category/view [id] => 8 ) [items] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [label] => SUIT SELECTIONS [url] => Array ( [0] => category/view [id] => 10 ) ) ) ) [1] => Array ( [label] => ENDING SOON [url] => Array ( [0] => category/view [id] => 9 ) ) ) ) 
         [2] => Array ( [label] => MEN [url] => Array ( [0] => category/view [id] => 4 ) ) 
         [3] => Array ( [label] => MAKE IT YOUR OWN [url] => Array ( [0] => category/view [id] => 5 ) ) 
         [4] => Array ( [label] => CLEARANCE [url] => Array ( [0] => category/view [id] => 6 ) ) 
         [5] => Array ( [label] => OUT OF THE BOX [url] => Array ( [0] => category/view [id] => 7 ) ) ) ) )
```

I want the array to start with `[items] => Array()`, how do I remove the parent node.

**The desired solution must be:**

```
Array ( 
         [0] => Array ( [label] => DESIGNERS [url] => Array ( [0] => category/view [id] => 2 ) ) 
         [1] => Array ( [label] => WOMEN [url] => Array ( [0] => category/view [id] => 3 ) [items] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [label] => CURRENT SALES [url] => Array ( [0] => category/view [id] => 8 ) [items] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [label] => SUIT SELECTIONS [url] => Array ( [0] => category/view [id] => 10 ) ) ) ) [1] => Array ( [label] => ENDING SOON [url] => Array ( [0] => category/view [id] => 9 ) ) ) ) 
         [2] => Array ( [label] => MEN [url] => Array ( [0] => category/view [id] => 4 ) ) 
         [3] => Array ( [label] => MAKE IT YOUR OWN [url] => Array ( [0] => category/view [id] => 5 ) ) 
         [4] => Array ( [label] => CLEARANCE [url] => Array ( [0] => category/view [id] => 6 ) ) 
         [5] => Array ( [label] => OUT OF THE BOX [url] => Array ( [0] => category/view [id] => 7 ) ) ) ) )
```

Comment: `$arrayYouWant = $otherArray['items'];`, or `$array = $array['items']` if you want to overwrite

Comment: I am getting `Undefined index: items`.

Comment: it is `$otherArray[0]['items']`

Comment: Check your input array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I understood well, is that what you want?

```
$desired_array=$old_array[0]['items']
```

Comment: I dont really think these kind of questions should be acknowledged with a reply. This level of questions should not be promoted IMO

Comment: @Martijn I agree, but it is here, so as long as there is no answer, it will stay open... OP can delete question, that's why down votes are here.

Comment: Nobody born intelligent. I am a beginner and I am learning. If you don't want to answer the question, don't do that. Nobody is forcing you.

Comment: @MohitBhansali I just answered to help you and said you can delete your question later because it will get down voted. If I didn't want to answer I wouldn't have done it.

Comment: (Actually, people are born intelligent, but without knowledge :) ) But besides that, this is very basic array knowledge. This can be found in the internet. You access the items the same way as you asign them to a variable

Comment: @CodeBird: Thanks. Indeed! Its working the way, I want.